How to detect LogCat crashing APK version in other Android devices
My app got rejected from the Play Store due to crashes, but the response email lacked details about the Android versions or crash locations.To resolve this issue, I'm seeking recommendations for a method that can provide comprehensive details about app performance across various Android versions. Any suggestions or guidance on debugging such issues efficiently? Thanks.
enter image description here
I'm seeking recommendations for a method that can provide comprehensive details about app performance across various Android versions

In my opinion, you could:
1 from Play Console, use a pre-launch report to identify issues
see https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842757?hl=en#zippy=%2Cview-pre-launch-report-summary
2 use Firebase Crashlytics which "is a lightweight, realtime crash reporter"
see https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics?authuser=0
